# Update multiple areas with jQuery.load()

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

jQuery allows you to update a single part of a page if it has an ID:

```
$('#myDiv').load('http://my/url/#myDiv');
```

I need to update several parts of a page (around a form). I realise I could:

- Call load one time per region I want to update, but this is crazy-inefficient.
- Restructure how I'm doing things, so detach the original form, `.load(...)` the whole page and reattach my old form... but this has a habit of messing around with focus states.

I guess what I'm after is a good way to download the page (as a jQuery object) and then cross-update particular sections. I'm assuming that's how  the existing `.load()` code works. But how do I actually do that?

Comment: `#myDiv` will be the same element that will be fetched from your `url` and when you say several parts of the page, I assume that there will be multiple `elements` with unique `id` and the same `element` will be present in the `url`  you give.. Correct me if my assumption is wrong.. It will be good if we get to see some example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to use [`$.get`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
$.get('http://my/url/', function(response) {
    var $page = $(response);

    $("#myDiv1").replaceWith($page.find("#myDiv1"));
    $("#myDiv2").replaceWith($page.find("#myDiv2"));
});
```

One important thing to note is that jQuery will remove elements like `<html>`, `<body>` or `<header>`, so if the element is a direct descendant of one of those, you could use `.filter` to find it instead.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking but couldn't find the code for. One of those days >_< Thank you!